# Occurrences of a number in a string

Tags: java, loops

I need to find the number of times that the number 1 occurs in a string such as "11100011"
so that I can then use the count to do some parity bit work.  I was wondering if anyone could tell me what method or how to set up a loop to do such a thing.

```
public class message
{
    private String parity1;
    private int count;

    public message(String Parity1)
    {
        parity1 = Parity1;
        int count = 0;
    }

    public static int countOnes(String parity1, char 1)
    {
        count = 0; 
        for(int i = 0; i < parity1.length(); i++) {
            if(parity1.charAt(i)==1){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
//...
```

Comment: blah blah blah what have you tried blah blah blah (IOW, read the FAQ)

Comment: Use a `for` loop and call `charAt` on the string.

Comment: So lets see what you have so far.

Comment: String ar = "111000011";
        int countOfOnes = ar.length() - ar.replaceAll("1", "").length();

Comment: There that is what I have I get an identifier expected error with char 1

Comment: Get rid of `char 1`. I don't know what you're trying to do there. Also, `parity1.charAt(i)==1` should be `parity1.charAt(i)=='1'`. There are other problems in your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your comparison:

```
if(parity1.charAt(i)=='1'){//note the quotes; needed to interpret '1' as a char
  count++;
}
```

Note this function signature is wrong:

```
public static int countOnes(String parity1, char 1)
```

and should be:

```
public static int countOnes(String parity1)
```

The second parameter isn't needed there. If you want to maybe pass in this parameter use:

```
public static int countOnes(String haystack, char needle)
```

And then your comparison becomes:

```
if(haystack.charAt(i)==needle){
```

Note, too, that `count` as declared in this method is wrong. You're trying to reference an object's member field from a static function. Static functions aren't associated with an object but with a class. Given that you don't need any member fields, you might as well just declare `count` within your `countOnes` function:

```
public static int countOnes(String parity1) {
  int count = 0;
  //...
}
```